# Why does :last-of-type not select the very last cell of a table?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-table

Could anyone help me to understand why

```
td:last-of-type { ... }
```

selects the last cell of each table row and not the very last cell of a table?

Answer (score 5):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-of-type-pseudo):

> The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last sibling of its type in the list of children **of its parent element.**

It's relative to the parent element, not the document. You probably want something like:

```
tr:last-child > td:last-child
```

Comment: Probably `tr:last-child > td:last-child`

Comment: This means that for each parent with a given set of childs the last child is chosen?

Comment: @VolkerAckermann: "this" being what the spec says or the selector?

Comment: @VolkerAckermann: The selector is parsed backwards, so for each child, if it's the last child in its parent, then it's added into the set of matched elements.

Comment: The spec doesn't say anything about the directionality of a selector. And besides, whether you look at it forwards or backwards, you're still going to look at each child and determine whether it's the last one in its parent...